# Gitlab OAuth configuration with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci

I have configured Jenkins using Gitlab OAuth configuration for authentication purpose

Gitlab API token is configured in Jenkins

[image]

Role based authentication is given for Gitlab user

Web hook configuration is done for the project in Gitlab

Jenkins init method is given like in below format

```
var jenkins = jenkinsapi.init('http://Gitlabuser:password@IP');
```

when navigate to http://Gitlabuser:password@IP link it goes to Gitlab login page

The question is

1. why the link navigates to gitlab login page even though Gitlab
   username and password provided in link
2. How to handle Jenkins Init method for Gitlab OAuth configuration

please let me know if any issues in the configuration also suggest a way to achieve gitlab OAuth configuration in Jenkins

Comment: I'm not sure but that configuration is to access jenkins with gitlab account, using OAuth2. So you have to login in gitlab after you'll have access to jenkins. The gitlab hook api is to handle event from gitlab to jenkins it is not linked with Oauth plugin.